# How do I pass ArrayList to another Activity using intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

In **Activity A**, I pass array using this code

```
 ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
 Intent i=new Intent(getApplication(),B.class);
 i.putExtra("results", results);
 startActivity(i);
```

In **Activity B**, receive `results`

```
ArrayList result;
result = (ArrayList<SearchResults>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");   
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**SearchResult**

```
public class SearchResults {

    private String weather = "";
    private String date = "";
    private String status = "";
    private String timeIn="";
    private String timeOut="";
    private String project="";
    private String description="";
    private String progress="";

    public void setWeather(String weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setTimeIn(String timeIn) {
        this.timeIn = timeIn;
    }

    public String getTimeIn() {
        return timeIn;
    }

    public void setTimeOut(String timeOut){
       this.timeOut=timeOut;
    }

    public String getTimeOut()
    {
        return timeOut;
    }

    public void setProject(String project){
        this.project=project;
    }

    public String getProject()
    {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProgress(String progress){
        this.progress=progress;
    }

    public String getProgress()
    {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

}
```

**Error LogCat**

```
 Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 2698
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.project.myapplication.bean.SearchResults@94c2757
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1397)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:738)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1344)
```

And this line

```
 startActivity(i);
```

How do I use `serializable` for passing bean objects and also make the bean class implements `serializable` ?  Thanks a lot.

---

In the same activity, I want the results saved to database.

```
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                WD.insertWorkDetails(result,a);  //a is pass from Activtity a too
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"DONE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

**WorkDetails**

```
 public long insertWorkDetails(ArrayList<SearchResults> listItems, long id)
    {
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        for(SearchResults s:listItems) {

            String Project = s.getProject();
            String temp = s.getDescription();
            String[] ReceiveDescription = temp.split(":");
            String Progress = s.getProgress();
            String[] ReceiveProgress = Progress.split(":");
            String TimeIn = s.getTimeIn();
            String[] ReceiveTimeIn = TimeIn.split(":");
            String TimeOut = s.getTimeOut();
            String[] ReceiveTimeOut = TimeOut.split(":");
           values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Project,Project);
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.WorkDescription,ReceiveDescription[1]);
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Percentage,ReceiveProgress[1]);
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeIn,ReceiveTimeIn[1]);
            values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut,ReceiveTimeOut[1]);
            values.put("Twd_id",id);
          database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_WORKDETAILS, null, values);
        }
        database.close();
        return 0 ;

    }
```

When I check my db, no listView item is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   com.example.project.myapplication.bean.SearchResults@94c2757

you are using `getSerializableExtra` to retrieve your `ArrayList`. This implies that `SearchResults` implements `Serializable` which is not the case. If you want an easy fix just let `SearchResults` implement the Serializable interface. In the case of SearchResults serialization will work out of the box. Or you could learn about `Parcelable` (read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)) and use it instead of `Serializable`. If you don't need to save the objects on your permanent storage, `Parcelable` is way more efficient than `Serializable`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I let `SearchResults` implement the `Serializable` interface ?

Comment: like every other interface. `public class SearchResults implements Serializable {`

Comment: Oh! Thanks you so much. If I want to get all the `SearchResults` items in Activity B, I can do in this way ?

Comment: yes you can. `String` and `Collections` implement `Serializable`. So it should work out of the box

Comment: I using `Toast` to display result in B, but `Toast` display `null`. Why would this happen ? I thought it will display something like `[com.example.project.myapplication.bean.SearchResults@94c2757]` ?

Comment: it should indeed. Could you create a gist with more code?

Comment: can I update my post or you want me create a new post?

Comment: I just add a Toast after result in Activity B, but it display null

Comment: I did understand that part. Without seeing the code that you are using it is impossible to say why it is happening

Comment: wait, I edit my code now. It display the value now but it shows nothing in my db. I hope you won't mind

Comment: you are filling up `results`, aren't you? Or are you passing the empty ArrayList?

Comment: But the Toast doesn't display null now

Comment: the Toast display that you passed an `ArrayList<SearchResults>`. It could still be empty tough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97720/discussion-between-seng-and-blackbelt).

Comment: I change `ArrayList result` in Activity B to  `ArrayList<SearchResults> result;`, still no luck